# изменить свойства элемента, если стоит фокус на дочернем элементе

Tags: css, css3, html

Приветствую

Подскажите как можно задать свойства элементу, если выбран (находится в фокусе его дочерний элемент)

Например

```
<div class = 'first'><input type = text class = 'second'></div>
```

Можно ли сделать что-то типа:

```
.first:if(.second:focus) {

}
```

?

т.е. мне не надо менять свойства дочернего элемента, но надо при изменении состояния дочернего элемента поменять свойства родительскому.

Comment: Нет, так нельзя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нет, на чистом css так не получится. Если нужно некие стили присвоить, можете посмотреть в сторону такого "костыля": внешний блок .first (relative) и обнуслить все стили. а внутри, после input положить блок (absolute), и ему присваивать стили

```css
.first {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
.first_style {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
input:focus + .first_style {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <input type="text">
  <div class="first_style"></div>
</div>
```

ну как-то так. или на js - при фокусе, присваивать класс, при потере фокуса отменять